# Accessing a large numpy array while preserving its order

Tags: performance, numpy, arrayaccess

I would like to access an numpy array `data` via an index `idx`, but still preserving the order in `data`. Below is an example where the array is accessed with an order different from the one in the original array.

```
In [125]: data = np.array([2, 2.2, 2.5])

In [126]: idx=np.array([1,0])

In [127]: data[idx]
Out[127]: array([2.2, 2. ])
```

I hope to get [2,2.2] instead. Is there a highly efficient way to do so? In my problem setting, I have the data with more than a million floating-point numbers, and idx with a 0.1 million integers.

**Important info**: The array `data` can be preprocessed if needed. The data come from an image processing work. For example, if we need to sort `data` beforehand, the time consumed on sorting would not be considered when measuring the performance. On the other hands, `idx` is something I would rather not process too much at runtime as time spent on it has to be counted. E.g. *soriting idx with an O(n log n) algorithm can be too expensive.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creat a boolean 'mask'

```
 mask = np.zeros(data.shape, bool)
 mask[idx] = True
 res = data[mask]
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? Or I didn't get the point?

```
data=np.array([2,2.2,2.5])
idx=np.array([1,0])
data[np.sort(idx)]
```

Comment: Where the output of the last command is:       >>> array([2. , 2.2])

Comment: Thanks, but "soriting idx with an O(n log n) algorithm can be too expensive." On the other hand, it is okay to sort data if needed. So my comments above.