# Form an item index in a masked array, calculate the index of the same item in the original sorted array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, processing-efficiency

I masked a *sorted* 1-D numpy array using the method below (which follows a solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076440/accessing-a-large-numpy-array-while-preserving-its-order)):

```
def get_from_sorted(sorted,idx):
     mask = np.zeros(sorted.shape, bool)
     mask[idx] = True
     return sorted[mask]
```

The python method returns the array after masking on the indexes `idx`. For example, if sorted=`np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3.0.4,0.5])`, and idx=`np.array([4,0,1]`), then the method `get_from_sorted` should return `np.array([0.1,0.2,0.5])` (note the order in the original array is preserved.)

Question: I need to get the mapping between the indices of the items in the array after masking and those in the original list. In the example above, such a mapping is

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 5
```

because 0.1, 0.2, and 0.5 is on the 0th, 1st, and 5th place in `sorted`.

How can I program this mapping efficiently?

**Requirement on efficiency:** Efficiency is the key in my problem solving. Here, both "idx"  and "sorted" is a 1-D array of 1 million elements, and idx is a 1-D array of about  0.5 million elements (taken from an image processing application). Thus, checking the elements of the masked array one by one, or in a vectorized fashion, against the original array, for example,  using np.where,  would not perform well in my case.  Ideally, there should be a relatively simply mathematical relation between the indices in the masked array and the original sorted array. Any idea?

Comment: I'm missing a point. What is an expected input and output?

Comment: Also  `0.5` is not the 5th item, it's 4th.

Comment: `np.flatnonzero`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume (from your example) that the original list is the sorted list. In which case, unless I misunderstand, you just do:

```
idx.sort()
```

and then the mapping is `i-> idx[i]`

Of course, if the original order of `idx` is important, make a copy first.

Answer (score 0):

A question is not clear for me. It can have several interpretations.

#### mask -> idx (in ascending order):

Let me try with this quite large dataset (10M of values, 10% of them are `True`):

```
x = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(10000000,), p=[0.9, 0.1])
```

In this case usage of `np.where` is quite effective:

```
%timeit np.where(x)[0]
%timeit x.nonzero()[0]
%timeit np.arange(len(x))[x]
24.8 ms ± 551 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
24.5 ms ± 229 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
52.4 ms ± 895 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### random items of sorted -> idx (in ascending order):

If you have lost any reference to positions of items you need to take from `sorted`, you're still able to find `idx` if there are no duplicate items. This is `O(n logn)`:

```
x = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(10000000,), p=[0.9, 0.1])
arr = np.linspace(0,1,len(x))
sub_arr = arr[x] %input data: skipping 90% of items

%timeit np.searchsorted(arr, sub_arr) %output data
112 ms ± 2.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### idx (in any order) -> idx (in ascending order)

this is just simple:

```
x = np.arange(10000000)
np.random.shuffle(x)
idx = x[:1000000] #input data: first 1M of random idx
%timeit np.sort(idx) #output data
65.3 ms ± 316 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know where the masked entries came from, you can use one of [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) or [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html). However, if you need to get the origins of only a subset of the indices, you can use a function I recently wrote as part of my library, haggis: [`haggis.npy_util.unmasked_index`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.npy_util.unmasked_index)<sup>1</sup>.

Given `mask` and the indices of some of your mask elements, you can retrieve a multi-dimensional index of the original locations with

```
unmasked_index(idx, mask)
```

If you ever need  it, there is also an inverse function [`haggis.npy_util.masked_index`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.npy_util.masked_index) that converts a location in a multidimensional input array into its index in the masked array.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Disclaimer: I am the author of haggis.</sup>